# If $\text{max}\{{|a+b|, |a-b|}\} < 1/2$ show $|a| < 1/2$ and $|b| < 1/2$ .

Tags: inequality

I am trying to prove this:

If $\text{max}\{|a+b|, |a-b|\} < \dfrac{1}{2}$ , show that: $$|a| < \frac{1}{2} \ ,\ |b| < \frac{1}{2}$$

I am not sure how I should approach this question, and I would really appreciate if anyone could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following three statements are equivalent:
\begin{align}
\max\{|a+b|&, |a-b|\} < \frac{1}{2} \\
|a+b| < \frac{1}{2} &\land |a-b| < \frac{1}{2} \\
-\frac{1}{2} < a+b < \frac{1}{2} &\land -\frac{1}{2} < a-b < \frac{1}{2} \tag1\label1
\end{align}
Adding the two inequalities in \eqref{1} yields
$$-1 < 2a < 1,$$
equivalently, $|a|<1/2$.
You can similarly obtain $|b|<1/2$ by combining the same two inequalities in a different way.

Comment: Added at the same time as my comment above. Note however $a$ and $b$ don't have to be real numbers; they can be complex numbers or vectors in a normed vector space.

Comment: Oh thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, we have: $2|a| = |2a| \le |a+b|+|a-b| < \dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}=1\implies |a| < \dfrac{1}{2}. $ Similarly, we have: $|b| < \dfrac{1}{2}$.